# Requeuing a successful task in Celery

Tags: python, mongodb, rabbitmq, celery

I have a certain type of task that does something that I would like refreshed a few minutes after it originally run, if a certain condition is met.

As far as I can see, there's no way to rerun a task that has previously run since the information about the task request (args, kwargs, priority..) is not saved anywhere.

I can see that it appears in Flower, but I assume that's because it uses Celery events.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want? I could add a post-task hook which saves the request info, but that seems a bit off.

I'm using RabbitMQ as the broker and MongoDB as the results backend.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs [apply_async](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) has a cowntdown option allowing you to delay the execution for a certain number of seconds.
You could just make a recursive task:

```
@app.task
def my_task(an_arg):
    # do something
    my_task.apply_async(countdown=120, kwargs={"an_arg": an_arg})
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear. I will not know that I even need to rerun the task until later (following some external input)